# Time zone abbreviation not returning it in double digit format

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

```
TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
```

It will return GMT+5:30 , my requirement is to have it as GMT+05:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the current time zone in a specific format, one way to do this is to use `DateFormatter` in a somewhat unorthodox way:

```
// formatter.timeZone is implicitly TimeZone.current
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "ZZZZ"

let abbreviation = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

This returns a string in the form of "GMT±xx:yy"; for me, this is "GMT-07:00".

See the [Date Field Symbol Table from TR35-31](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Away from my compiler to test but this should do the trick.

```
let tz = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() 
if tz.contains(“+11”) || tz.contains(“+12”) {
// do nothing
} else {
    tz.replaceAlOcurrences(of: “+”,  with: “+0”)
}
```